# Conditional concatenation in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a three sets of code (code1, code 2 and code 3) having alphanumeric objects. All the codes are separated by delimiter (;) , and the codes are related based on sequence like A123 of code 1 is related to A of code 2 and A445 of code 3, and so on. Code 3 has some codes duplicated or repeated.

My desired output is to get the concatenated "code 4"  where code 1 and code 2 are concatenated based on either of these two conditions

a) if the corresponding code in code 3 has no repeated value

b) if the corresponding code in code 3 has repeated value, then the position corresponding to the position of last repeated value in code 3 needs to be used for concatenating code 1 and code 2 (like B678 R4 because A445 is repeated twice in code 3, and the 4th position of A445 needs to be considered for concatenating code 1 and code 2)

Let me know if any logic can be used to get the output. Thanks in advance!

Python script for dataframe df is

```
df11 = pd.DataFrame({"code1": ["A123; A321; B478; B678; C567", "A321; A821; B448; B698; C577"], "code2": ["A; B5; N5; R4; H5", "A3; B; N; R7; H2"],"code3": ["A445; A323; A323; A445; A659", "A328; A328; A621; A442; A621"]},      index=[0, 1], )
```

Desired output along with the input codes should look like this
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### STEPS:

1. use `applymap` to convert each value into a list.
2. `explode` the dataframe.
3. strip off the extra space if any.
4. drop the duplicates in the df based on the `code3` column and keep the last value.
5. drop the `code3` column and join `code1 & code2`.
6. Finally, aggregate them back using `groupby` to get the desired output.

```
df2 =(
    df11.assign(
        desired_output=df11.applymap(
            lambda x: x.split(';'))
        .apply(pd.Series.explode)
        .applymap(str.strip)
        .drop_duplicates(subset='code3', keep='last')
        .drop('code3', 1)
        .apply(' '.join, 1)
        .groupby(level=0)
        .agg('; '.join))
)
```

UPDATED ANSWER:

```
df2 = (
    df11.assign(
        desired_output=
        df11.apply(lambda s: s.str.split('; ').explode().str.strip())
        .drop_duplicates(subset='code3', keep='last')
        .drop('code3', 1)
        .apply(' '.join, 1)
        .groupby(level=0)
        .agg('; '.join)
        )
)
```

OUTPUT:

```
                          code1              code2  \
0  A123; A321; B478; B678; C567  A; B5; N5; R4; H5   
1  A321; A821; B448; B698; C577   A3; B; N; R7; H2   

                          code3             desired_output  
0  A445; A323; A323; A445; A659  B478 N5; B678 R4; C567 H5  
1  A328; A328; A621; A442; A621   A821 B; B698 R7; C577 H2
```

Comment: wow! I would need many more years of practice to achieve such expert manipulation!

Comment: @Nk03 Good answer, although you can substantially reduce the number of apply/apply maps steps, for e.g you could split the strings in a vectorized manner using  `df.apply(lambda s: s.str.split('; ').explode())`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I was not aware of the fact that we can use `explode` inside `apply`. Thanks !! :)

Comment: @Nk03 I have some issue with drop duplicate command while solving similar problem, i have created a new thread and linked it (see the Linked section) .

Answer (score 2):

I have done a few manipulations:

(1) Use regular expression to extract items into a list, and reverse the list order.

(2) Find the index(s) of unique items in 'Code 3'.

(3) Concat the corresponding values in 'Code 1' and 'Code 2' based on the index(s).

```
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({"code1": ["A123; A321; B478; B678; C567", "A321; A821; B448; B698; C577"], "code2": ["A; B5; N5; R4; H5", "A3; B; N; R7; H2"],"code3": ["A445; A323; A323; A445; A659", "A328; A328; A621; A442; A621"]},      index=[0, 1], )
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: re.findall(r'\w+', x)).apply(lambda x: x[::-1])

df['idx'] = df['code3'].apply(lambda x: [x.index(e) for e in set(x)])
df['code4'] = df.apply(lambda row: [row['code1'][i] + ' ' + row['code2'][i] for i in row['idx']], axis=1)
```

Output df

```
    code1                           code2               code3                           idx         code4
0   [C567, B678, B478, A321, A123]  [H5, R4, N5, B5, A] [A659, A445, A323, A323, A445]  [0, 2, 1]   [C567 H5, B478 N5, B678 R4]
1   [C577, B698, B448, A821, A321]  [H2, R7, N, B, A3]  [A621, A442, A621, A328, A328]  [0, 3, 1]   [C577 H2, A821 B, B698 R7]
```